# What can I use instead of remote desktop to reach my home server?

Tags: windows-7, remote

Remote Desktop and Logmein is banned at work, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Tempted to edit this title to "Good ways to get fired?"

Comment: Another unfortunate shiny example why users are the weakest link and a domains highest security risk...ignorance is bliss!

Comment: I'd say the alternative is to ask the IT department at your work what remote access programs they would allow.  This will either suffice to provide you with the alternative you seek, or it will provide you with the concrete reasoning that you are not allowed to do this.  Of course, if you are already aware of the fact that you are not allowed to do this, but you are seeking to circumvent security, then the first comment here applies aptly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several alternatives to Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe). But the question is if you are allowed to do this anyway. If the company has an IT policy that forbids this kind of activity then you are looking for trouble.

But what do I care...

You can try [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/), [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/), [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/), or [join.me](https://join.me/) (from the makers of LogMeIn).

Answer (score 1):

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) is very popular and free for personal use.  However, if they detect logmein, they probably will detect Teamviewer.